# ¿Cómo excluir ciertos números con random.randint?

Tags: python, random

¿Habrá alguna posibilidad de excluir por ejemplo: el número 50, 99, 80 por para que no se imprima?

```
x = (random.randint(1, 100))
print(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Te copio tal cual lo que pone en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999093/generate-random-number-in-range-excluding-some-numbers/42999212) pregunta:

```
from random import choice

print(choice([i for i in range(0,9) if i not in [2,5,7]]))
```

En tu caso `print(choice([i for i in range(1,101) if i not in [50,99,80]]))`

Como añade César en los comentarios, el rango que devuelve `random.randint` es inclusivo, por lo que para que incluya el 100, deberías poner 101.

Comment: De hecho, en el caso de él sería `range(1, 101)` porque el rango usado por `random.randint` es inclusivo.

Comment: Cierto @César, lo modifico, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Una aproximación parecida pero algo distinta a la respuesta de Adrián, siempre que la lista de casos sea relativamente pequeña, es:

- generar una lista con todos lo valores posibles a elegir
- generar un valor random pero para usar como índice de selección de la lista.

  ```
  import random
  elementos = [n for n in range(0, 101) if n not in [50, 99, 80]]
  x = elementos[random.randint(0, len(elementos))]
  ```

Eventualmente puede ser más óptima si la cantidad de valores excluidos es importante.

Comment: La última parte debería empezar de 0, sería `elementos[random.randint(0, len(elementos) - 1)]` sino estás excluyendo el primer elemento, y al final restartle uno para que no de un `IndexError`. Recuerda que son posiciones de una lista.

Comment: @César, es totalmente cierto, estaba en modo R (dónde las posiciones arrancan de 1)

Comment: Hasta ahora no entiendo por qué demonios se les ocurrió a los de R empezar desde 1. No lo uso muy seguido pero para la maestría nos enseñaron un poco y todos andábamos como locos por esa decisión que tomó R.